# Why can't I create a UI for my Add-In in Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, add-in

I don't know why the below checkbox is greyed out, I have general development settings and VS Ultimate as shown.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does your add-in project name include a period?  This would be sufficient to disable the tools menu option in the wizard.  (See the note at step 4 at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/80493a3w.aspx for details.)